# Creating bindable property with Xamarin C# gave No property, bindable property found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I created a class derived from `StackLayout`:

```
public class MyStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    private readonly BindableProperty TriggerTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("TriggerType", typeof(string), typeof(MyStackLayout), defaultValue: "test", propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => OnTriggerTypePropChanged(b, (string)o, (string)n));

    public string TriggerType
    {
      get
      {
        return (string)GetValue(TriggerTypeProperty);
      }
      set
      {
        SetValue(TriggerTypeProperty, value);
      }
    }

    private static void OnTriggerTypePropChanged(BindableObject bindable, string oldvalue, string newvalue)
    {
      var obj = bindable as MyStackLayout;
      if (obj == null)
      {
        return;
      }

      obj.TriggerType = newvalue;
    }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<controls1:MyStackLayout IsVisible="False" TriggerType="{Binding AStringPropertyFromViewModel}">
   ...
</controls1:MyStackLayout>
```

I got error:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'TriggerType', or
>   mismatching type between value and property.

What's wrong ?

If I use in XAML `TriggerType="A string"` works fine, if I use `{Binding ...}` won't work.

Comment: What is your ViewModel? Did you hook it up to the BindingContext property? And does the property actually exist?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis: View model is a simple class with one property `public string AStringPropertyFromViewModel {get;set;}` and yes, it is binded through `BindingContext`

Comment: Someone else complains here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100308/binding-a-custom-bindable-property-to-a-property-in-the-view-model-custom-listview and no solution posted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Xamarin docs, here is how to define a bindable property:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty =
BindableProperty.Create ("EventName", typeof(string),typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
```

Try to change your bindable property from private to public to see if it solve your issue.

The link for the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties